# ASP.NET MVC3 Model Validation DataAnnotations to do less than or equal to another property with client side validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have a simple form which is using ASP.NET MVC 3 unobtrusive client side validation.

The model looks a bit like this (names changed for privacy):

```
public class MyInputModel
{
    public MyInputModel()
    {
    }

    public MyInputModel(MyViewData viewData)
    {
        ViewData = viewData;
        MaxValueForSize = viewData.MaxSize;
    }

    public int MaxValueForSize { get; set; }


    [RegularExpression("[1-9][0-9]*",ErrorMessage = "The value must be a whole number.")]
    public int Size { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    [Required]
    public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

In my view I put a hidden field in for `MaxValueForSize` and I want to compare the entered value for `Size` to less than or equal to the `MaxValueForSize` property.

I know I can do this server side by overriding validation attribute like so:

```
internal class SizeValidAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if(value != null)
        {
            var model = (MyInputModel) validationContext.ObjectInstance;


            if ((int)value > model.MaxValueForSize)
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);

        }
        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
}
```

However I would like to (need to) have client side validation on this property. Similar to how the `Compare` annotation works.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Do I need to extend the client side validation somehow?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this article.  It explains how to extend the ASP.NET MVC model validation to support cross-field validation:

**Extending ASP.NET MVC’s Validation** 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/10/05/extending-asp-net-mvc-s-validation.aspx

Comment: This solution was really helpful. I tried it in MVC2 and it worked but I had to put the model properties in the proper order. It appears that the setting of a property value and running that properties validation is on the same loop. If you want to access another property in the model then it needs to come first (by line number) so that it will be set first. So be careful, its a trap!

Answer (score 2):

Robert Harvey's answer put me on the right path but it is possible with ASP.NET MVC3 to quite simply override the validation using the following pattern:

```
public class LessThanOrEqualToPropertyAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(OtherProperty);

            var otherValue = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod().Invoke(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if ((int)otherValue < (int)value)
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);

        }
        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ValidationType = "lessthanorequaltoproperty",
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(ErrorMessage),
        };

        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("otherproperty", OtherProperty);

        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

This wasn't exactly clear from the various conflicting documentation I found.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but to piggy back on RSL's excellent self-answer, the only thing really missing was the client script to add an unobtrusive validation adapter.  Good example of such over [here](http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=183#.T1jvHvVdAtX).